# display: flex with margin, inside another div, leaves white area when no previous content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

wondering if this is a browser bug?

Having a div with background red, then inside a div with `display: flex; margin-top: 1rem;` leaves a white margin, instead of red. Removing `display: flex` OR adding some content before flex solves the issue.

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div style="background: #400; height: 500px;">
    <!-- adding a &nbsp; here makes the top part #400 too, as it should be -->
    <div style="background: #080;  margin-top: 1rem; display: flex; ">test2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: screenshot]